# How to apply advanced search on datatable using input text and select?

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables, jquery-plugins

I tried many of different way to apply advanced search on table using Datatable with all of input text and dropdown select but not working with me this is example of my code could anyone help me with my problem and this I want When I fill all the search filed than click on filter button show data in table.

http://live.datatables.net/piqidoqo/636/edit

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this link [Search API](https://datatables.net/examples/api/regex.html). I was able to implement custom search for input using the example.

Comment: @BonishKoirala thank you so much it helps me a lot :)

Comment: If it's okay with you, I am gonna put this as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [search API](https://datatables.net/examples/api/regex.html) provides a way to add custom search in your datatables.